# Autoupdatable properties in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, events, properties, delegates, auto-update

I am a beginner VB.NET programmer and I am trying to implement a class `Principal` with two members which are instances of two different classes.

As I am learning how to use events and delegates I would like to implement an event (if this could be a solution to my problem) to update `objeto2._atributoC21` when a value is assign to `objeto1.atributoC11` and then update `Principal.total` with the sum of all members of `object1` and `object2`.

Here is a very rude code but to make this example as clear as it would be possible:

```
Public Class Principal
    Public objeto1 As ClaseIncluida1
    Public objeto2 As ClaseIncluida2
    Public total As Integer
End Class

Public Class ClaseIncluida1
    Private _atributoC11 As Integer
    Public _atributoC12 As Integer

    Public Property atributoC11 As Integer
        Get
            Return _atributoC11
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _atributoC11 = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class ClaseIncluida2
    Public _atributoC21 As Integer
    Public _atributoC22 As Integer
End Class
```

I know how to use events and delegates in a simple way, but when I try to make what I have described above I find myself in a dead end way.

Maybe events and delegates are no suitable for `Principal` class, but in that case, how could I implement a suitable solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic built-in way to do that kind of thing.  If you want to do that, you will need to implement the plumbing yourself.  The standard way to do it is by having the "child" classes, if you will, implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms133020.aspx) interface.  Then, the "parent" class can listen to their `PropertyChanged` events.  When either of the child objects raise that event, the parent object can handle it appropriately.  In your case, you'd want to handle it by updating the `total`.  For instance:

```
Public Class Principal
    Public WithEvents objeto1 As ClaseIncluida1
    Public WithEvents objeto2 As ClaseIncluida2
    Public total As Integer

    Private Sub PropertyChangedHandler(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles objeto1.PropertyChanged, objeto2.PropertyChanged
        total = ...
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ClaseIncluida1
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _atributoC11 As Integer
    Public _atributoC12 As Integer

    Public Property atributoC11 As Integer
        Get
            Return _atributoC11
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _atributoC11 = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("atributoC11"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class

Public Class ClaseIncluida2
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public _atributoC21 As Integer
    Public _atributoC22 As Integer

    'Implement raising event when properties change

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```